# Quantum mechanics, Fourier transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, fourier-transform, commutator

Why do we use $p=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in quantum physics? (I know the reason for $i\hbar$, quantization). Is this right to say we can't measure velocity and position of electrons at the same time, so we use mathematical method, Fourier transformation?

Comment: You can find a motivation of $p=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
in [Wikipedia:Momentum operator:Origin from De Broglie plane waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator#Origin_from_De_Broglie_plane_waves).

Answer (score 4):

We define the quantum Poisson bracket for the operators corresponding to dynamical variables $u$ and $v$ as $${\{u,v\}}=uv-vu=i\hbar[u,v]$$ where $[u,v]$ is the classical Poisson bracket. For the simple case of momentum and position (considering one dimension for simplicity), we get $$xp-px=i\hbar.\tag{*}$$ We now define the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ acting on a ket $|\psi\rangle$ as $$\frac{d}{dx}|\psi\rangle=|\frac{d\psi}{dx}\rangle.$$ Using this we get $$\frac{d}{dx}x-x\frac{d}{dx}=1.$$ From here we can see that $$p=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$$ satisfies the commutation relation $(*)$. Now it is not necessary for us to take $p$ as defined above but with a bit more work it can be shown that choosing a suitable representation (basis) allows (forces) us to take $p$ as above.

Refer to section $22$ of Principle of Quantum Mechanics by Dirac ($4^{th}$ edition) for more details.

Comment: Simple and good answer.

Comment: You answer is true comes from the plane wave function for a free particle ,it is also similar to  tangent vector (intrinsic) we take x as parameter  ,using ih ,again we reach ih {\partial}{\partial x}$ , but  why we take it as p?  however , I think there is a problem with these ,is there any Physical justification  ?

Comment: @JohnChambers I think what you're asking, correct me if I'm wrong, is why we take $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$ to be $p$ even if it satisfies the commutation relation. That is simply because we started with the classical Poisson bracket ***for*** $x$ and $p$, i.e., we got the commutation relation ***for*** $x$ and $p$ ***from*** the classical Poisson bracket ***for $x$ and $p$***.

Comment: @JohnChambers And what you're asking physical justification for is not clear.

Comment: On suggestion, $\psi\rangle$ has been changed to $|\psi\rangle$ as it might cause confusion to some readers. However, it must be pointed that the former notation ***is correct*** and the $|$ is unnecessary as Dirac showed.

Comment: You're right, it is simple to get that formula ,but again i didn't understand the concept of momentum in quantum physics

Comment: @John You might find [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77457/what-is-the-momentum-operator) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_operator) helpful.